# Decoupling ion.rangeSlider grid / tooltip values

Tags: ion-range-slider

This seems like a simple enough thing to do. I have a simple slider which goes from 0 to 100 in steps on 25. When using the slider I would like to change the number returned by a string:

0 - Novice
25 - Beginner
50 - Intermediate
75 - Advance
100 - Expert

However, I can't seem to find a way to decouple the grid value (0 - 100) from the tooltip value returned.

Thanks in advance.

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

From Denis himself, this jsfiddle provides a great starting point to get to a working solutions:

`not sure why SO wants to see the code here ...`

http://jsfiddle.net/njn74oqw/1/

Carlos